# ReactJS one app, multiple websites, single backend

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I'm trying to create a ReactJS web app that I can use on multiple websites (clone ?), while it fetches data from a centralized API.

The goal is to develop one app, which I can improve and update, of which I automatically deploy to each website.

What's the best approach to do that?

Comment: not sure if you can do an "automatic" deploy across multiple websites for a react component, but you can create one big component and replace it in each site after a change to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the simplest way is to have one repositroy all your website use the same repo for your react js app. And you can add and .env file for each website that contain a specifique configuration for each app.

this way you will share the same app , you update one repo and update is shared cross your websites.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this I discovered to create environment variables that get passed to the backend through a custom header for example. It's a way of creating a SaaS website.